# How could I auto execute ban command in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I relatively new in that Python field (I have notions of C++) and I would want to create a bot that auto execute ban as soon as it detects russian bots with cyrillic characters in their nicks entering in the group.

I copy-pasted several parts of different examples and I don't know if I'm doing well. Here is the code:

```
import re 
import logging
 
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Filters,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext,
)
 
  updater = Updater("<MY-BOT-TOKEN>")
 
    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
 
    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
 
    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))
 
    def has_cyrillic(text):
    return bool(re.search('[а-яА-Я]', text))
 
    def add_group(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        for member in update.message.new_chat_members:
            if has_cyrillic(member.full_name):
                --- SUPPOSEDLY, AUTO BAN WOULD BE HERE ---
                update.message.reply_text("{member.full_name} has been banned")
            else:
                update.message.reply_text("{member.full_name} just joined the group")
 
    add_group_handle = MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.new_chat_members, add_group)
 
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
 
    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()
```

I'm using the newest version of Python and python-telegram-bot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've placed your **private BOT token** in the question. I removed it, but it's still visible in the history. Consider renewing the token at @botFather to prevent other people abusing it!

Comment: Thanks! Anyway this is a test bot, I would create another one with the final code

Comment: Your name, private ID and text messages are visible for anyone calling getUpdates with your token, consider renewing it now.

Comment: Ok! I already revoked it